# Bootstrap: Fixed-grid table to stacked list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

New to Bootstrap and trying to figure out something simple:

For tablet and desktop viewports, I want a fixed-width table to be used as a calendar: no relative sizing (percentages), just fixed width and heights.

For mobile, all the 'cells' in this table should stack.  So far I have the basic bootstrap setup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">Sunday</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">Monday</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">Tuesday</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">Wednesday</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">Thursday</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">Friday</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">Saturday</div>
  </div>
  ...
```

Questions/Problems:

1) This only stacks if I use "col-sm-1", but then that stacks too 'soon' on a desktop browser; I'd rather use xs but I'm not sure how to make that stack.

2) Is there any canonical way to make the 'cells' fixed-width and height without breaking the bootstrap model?

Comment: You can edit your bootstrap.css file to the specific display settings.  Not recommended, especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: Agreed; I feel like what I'm trying to do should be doable with the defaults...

Comment: Use Javascript based on viewport size to alter the css class of the elements.

Comment: @humble.rumble, even if I do that, how would I make it so that xs 'cells' stack? Or accomplish the second question?